# iOS Segue Animation Beginner with a query

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, segue

Okay guys/gals, here's what I'm looking to do, I'd love some pointers to a good tutorial or a good explanation on how to do this. As much as I'd love someone to post code here, I need to learn how to do this for future projects and overall feel good points.(I've searched myself but could only find swift tutorials which were similar but not the same)

Imagine a screen with a circular button in the middle, wait you don't have to[image: massive picture with button in middle]

Sorry about the size, I want to press that button and perform a segue which expands from that button, eventually filling the screen with the new red screen. So in essence the button grows and fill the screen but really I'm transitioning to a new screen.

Any pointers greatly appreciated. Thanks.

A minor detail: this is the only screen on storyboard at present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do a couple of non-obvious things to make this work.  First, get rid of button constraints in the storyboard.  Second, add a line to my `viewDidLoad` to derive constraints.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.redButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
}
```

Then, for the actual effect I create an animation when the button is pressed.  The `animated:NO` bit in the completion handler prevents extra visual noise.

```
- (IBAction)redButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        self.redButton.frame = self.view.frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"redController"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

I used a simple button object for this.  To make it work with a round image, you may have to play with the new frame size a bit.

Comment: This is a pretty neat answer and works very nicely for the effect I'm looking for, I'm going to mark it as the right answer even though it not technically what I asked but I like when people think outside the box. Thanks a lot

Comment: Since both an animation and a segue use the main thread, there's no real way I can think of to make them happen at the same time.  Maybe you could invent a new type of segue that handled both things but I suspect that would be just a different way of hiding the fact they were serial operations.

Comment: Okay, so basically this is the way to do this...I salute your knowledge! thank you